# How to establish a Laravel Eloquent model through 3+ tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Currently working on a very basic three table/model problem in Laravel and the proper Eloquent setup has my brain leaking.

COLLECTION -> coll_id, ...

ITEM -> item_id, coll_id, type_id, ...

TYPE -> type_id, ...

I can phrase it a thousand ways but cannot begin to conceptualize the appropriate Eloquent relationships:

COLLECTIONS have many ITEMS, each ITEM has a TYPE. Or, an ITEM belongs to a single COLLECTION, TYPES are associated with many ITEMS.

To me COLLECTION and ITEM are key, while TYPE is really additional reference data on a given ITEM; basically a category for the item.

My objective is to build a solution where users create COLLECTIONS, add ITEMS to those COLLECTIONS, and those ITEMS are associated with one of many TYPES (which they will also define).

I know this example isn't far from other Author, Book, Category; or City, State, Country examples but implementing those model frameworks doesn't build the full connection from COLLECTION<->ITEM<->TYPE and most obviously fails when trying to associate TYPES within a COLLECTION.

Models:

COLLECTION

```
class Collection extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }

    public function types()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Type::class, Item::class);
    }

}
```

ITEM

```
class Item extends Model
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Collection::class);
    }

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Type::class);
    }
}
```

TYPE

```
class Type extends Model
{
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }

}
```

These models have COLLECTION<->ITEM in both directions working well, but the wheels fall off when I try to integrate TYPE. Depending on the 1000 variations I've tried I either get NULL in Tinker or it's looking for an ITEM_ID in TYPE which doesn't and shouldn't exist.

What would a solution be to update the model to accurately reflect ITEMS having one TYPE and the eventual set of TYPES within a COLLECTION?

Thanks in advance!

---

UPDATE: Working *nested* solution - the primary response solution was showing 2 relations at COLLECTION, no nesting:

```
class Collection extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
```

```
class Item extends Model
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Collection::class);
    }

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsto(Type::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Type extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
}
```

```
$collection->load('items.type');

        dd($collection);
```

```
Collection {#280 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "collections"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:5 [▶]
  #original: array:5 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  **#relations: array:1** [▼
    "items" => Collection {#285 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Item {#288 ▼
          #connection: "mysql"
          #table: "items"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:13 [▶]
          #original: array:13 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          **#relations: array:1** [▼
            "type" => Type {#296 ▶}
          ]
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #fillable: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
        }
        1 => Item {#289 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: You seem to have the wrong relationship on the Item model for `collection()`. A `HasOne` would mean the Collection table has a foreign key to the Item table. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HasManyThrough` isn't the right relationship between Collection and Type. `HasManyThrough` is kind of like chaining 2 `HasMany` relationships together:

```
Country -> State -> City
```

Notice how the arrows all go one way. That's because City has a foreign key to State, and State has a foreign key to Country.

Your relationship looks like this:

```
Collection -> Item <- Type
```

So Item has foreign keys to both Collection and Type. In this case, the relationship between Collection and Type is actually `BelongsToMany`, and the Item table is the join table.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

```php
class Collection extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }

    public function types()
    {
        // Substitute your table and key names here
        return $this->belongsToMany(Type::class, 'items_table', 'coll_id', 'type_id');
    }

}

class Type extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }

    public function collections()
    {
        // Substitute your table and key names here
        return $this->belongsToMany(Collection::class, 'items_table', 'type_id', 'coll_id');
    }

}

class Item extends Model
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->belongsto(Collection::class);
    }

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsto(Type::class);
    }
}
```

If you want to get collections with their items, and the corresponding type under each item, you can do:

```
Collection::with(['items.type'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the item first then get the item type through your relationship.

```
public function getCollectionOfItemsBaseOnType($type){

$collections = Collection::all();
$items = [];
  foreach($collections as $collection){
   if($collection->item->type == $type){
       array_push($items, $collection->item);    
   }
  }
}
return $items;
```