# Laravel Eloquent Several relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have three models that I made simple for the example (a user make a request to get a phone) :

1. `User`

   - id
   - login
2. `Request`

   - id
   - user_id
   - phone_id
3. `Phone`

   - id
   - name

The relations are below :

In **User model** :

```
public function requests()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Requests');
}
```

In **Phone model** :

```
public function phoneRequests()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Requests');
    // But it returns null
}
```

I need to get a collection where I start from the User model and I get all the requested phones (I need there name). The problem is that phone_id is in Requests Model and in the documentation this is inverse.

I can not find any relationship to reach my goal.

The ideal would be to go through the following relation :

```
Auth::user()->requests->phoneRequests
// Would returns the phone name the user has requested
```

I also tried to do it with a raw SQL query but I'd rather using relationships. How to do this ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Jonas is right, this is a `belongsToMany` relationship between user and phone, with requests being the join table. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606827/how-to-establish-a-laravel-eloquent-model-through-3-tables/56607151#56607151

Comment: @newUserName02 +1 on your answer, this helped me a lot ! Will answer in this topic. Solution is very simple. I just followed the documentation but with your answer in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [newUserName02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606827/how-to-establish-a-laravel-eloquent-model-through-3-tables/56607151#56607151)'s comment, the solution for my question is :

```
/**
 * Returns all requests made by this client
 * @return Collection
 */
public function requests()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Requests');
}

/**
 * Returns all the phones requested by the client
 * @return Collection
 */
public function phones()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Phone', 'phone_request');
    // where phone_request is the name of the pivot table (App\Requests)
}
```

Also, I invite you to consult [this excellent article](https://laravel.sillo.org/les-relations-avec-eloquent-12/) (in French) which explains well the relations with schemas.

Answer (score 1):

You should have in your `Requests` model a phone relationship, like this:

```
public function phone()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Phone');
}
```

So now you can get all the requests with the phone for the user like so:

```
$user->requests->first()->phone; // this is for the first request, but you can get the phone for each request in a loop, I guess you know how to do that.
```

And also note that your relationship in the Phone model is wrong hence the reason for getting null. That one should be again hasMany as in the User because a Phone can have many requests as per your table structure.

In your `Phone` model you should have this:

```
public function requests()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Requests', 'phone_id');
}
```

Because a phone can belong to many requests as per your DB structure.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've try everything. It always returns null. I feel that the relationship isn't happening. Can you update your answer because I didn't understand the last point please ?

Comment: You can debug what does `Auth::user()->requests` returns?

Comment: Thank you for your good answer, I found a better solution for my problem.